# When I give input as 3,I get the result printed for 4 times.Can you please let me know why is that so?I am new to python

Tags: python, factorial

```
def fact(num,i,originalinput):
    while(i<originalinput):
         num=num*i
         i=i+1
         fact(num,i,originalinput)
     print(num)    
num=int(input("enter num"))
originalinput=num/
i=1
```

//calling the function

*When I execute this with input : 3.*
*6*
*6*
*6*
*6*

Comment: what are the values of num i and originalinput are you feeding into it

Comment: Are you calling `fact()` 4 times or is it being looped and executed 4 times, check your code that may be the case

Comment: num is the input i get from the user which is 3 for now and i am storing num in originalinput and i is just a variable initialised to 1.So,num=3,originalinput=3,i=1

Comment: [Some helpful links](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Drecursive+factorial)